# Taking too much time to retrieve rows from SQLite

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I am new to iOS.  I am trying to implement a SQLite database.

My problem is that when I go to fetch data from database, it takes a lot of time even though there are only 50 records inside the tables.

I did make a separate method for fetching data because many times I need to retrieve data for different tables.

My method:

```
-(NSArray*)fetch_data:(NSString *)table_name fields_arr:(NSMutableArray *)fields_arr{

    NSArray *dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docsDir = dirPaths[0];

    databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"test.db"]];

    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_stmt *SelectStatement;
        NSMutableDictionary *record_dict;

        NSString *SelectQry=@"select ";
        NSString *lastField = [fields_arr lastObject];
        for (int i =0; i<[fields_arr count]; i++) {
            if (fields_arr[i] == lastField) {
                SelectQry = [SelectQry stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",fields_arr[i]]];
            } else {
                SelectQry = [SelectQry stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,",fields_arr[i]]];
            }
        }

        SelectQry = [SelectQry stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"from %@",table_name]];


        const char *query_stmt = [SelectQry UTF8String];
        NSMutableArray *resultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,
                               query_stmt, -1, &SelectStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {

            while(sqlite3_step(SelectStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {

                record_dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];


                for (int i = 0; i<[fields_arr count]; i++) {
                    NSString *field_value = [[NSString alloc]init];
                    field_value = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                                  (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(SelectStatement, i)];
                    [record_dict setValue:field_value forKey:fields_arr[i]];

                }
                [resultArray addObject:record_dict];

            }
            return resultArray;
            //sqlite3_reset(statement);
            sqlite3_finalize(SelectStatement);
        }
        else{
                sqlite3_finalize(SelectStatement);
                return nil;
        }
}
```

Comment: Optimize your code...In your code there are more then one for loop, Thats why it's taking a time.

Comment: @DipenChudasama :: thx for replaying ....i know but is there any solution how can i improve the performance???

Comment: There is a library on github "FMDB" its a wrapper on sqlite https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb 
and also perform any fetching in background will increase performance rather than fetching on main thread.

Comment: @MuhammadWaqas :: thx for replying...any other way??? ...do not want to third party

Comment: I don't know what your want to achieve but one thing keep in mind always perform data fetching in background thread and avoid to use a lot of loops as it will increase time complexity of your algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are opening database connection for each time method is called for fetching data. This is not appropriate way. You must establish connection only once and use it.

```
+(sqlite3 *)openDatabase{
if (database == NULL) {
  NSString* str_path=[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

  NSString *path = [str_path stringByAppendingPathComponent:strDatabaseName];
  if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
    NSLog(@"Database Successfully Opened");
  }
  else {
    NSLog(@"Error in opening database");
    database = NULL;
  }
}
return database;}
```

You can call this on app launch from app delegate and define this method in a class where you are defining other DB methods. I hope it will reduce some overhead and will reduce some time too.

Comment: Don't forget to do an appropriate close operation when the app ends.

Comment: (It's a little hard to parse the OP's code, but it appears that he doesn't close the DB, so more and more open instances are being created as the program runs.)